# Можно ли в яндекс картах заменить маркер на свой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, можно ли в яндекс картах заменить маркер (указатель на карте) и всплывающую подсказку на свои? Если да, то как?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=bq0oFU4NUff_4fz6EsPcOlWbgl28epow&width=600&height=450"></script>
```

[ссылка на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/q00z4qr5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно, вот более точная ссылка на "песочницу" Яндекса с интересующей задачей - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage

Comment: Спасибо @xaja. Но у меня 2 вопроса:
1 - почему при добавлении яндекс карт на сайт wordpress не видно хинта 2 - почему прозрачный фон хинта становится белым?
http://jsfiddle.net/9fywhmc0/

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы хотите? что за хинт 2? почему у хинта должен быть прозрачный фон? каков конечный результат должен быть

Comment: вы по фидлу переходили? и раз выкладывали ссылку на песочницу, то я думал что знаете, что такое хинт.. по фидлу как вы можете вижеть - на метке всплывает подсказка картинка(хинт). она изначально на прозрачном фоне, а отображается на карте белым. 2 при интеграции карты на вордпресс - хинт вообще не показывает

Comment: кто сказал что хинт должен быть прозрачным? в этом же примере явно видно что хинт имеет белый фон. 2 пункт никто вам не скажет, не видя ситуацию уже конкретного проекта

Comment: в том-то и дело, что пнг с прозрачным фоном, а не белым! а в апи яндекса выводит белым!

Comment: потому что хинт сам по себе с белым фоном, и СВЕРХУ него лежит картинка с прозрачным. Пройдите на кухню и положите на стол (НЕ прозрачный) прозрачную тарелку. Ну и как? Виден пол?

Answer (score 5):

Да, можно. Исчерпывающее описание решения данной проблемы можно найти в [официальной документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage/).

Comment: может подскажите почему: 1 - почему при добавлении яндекс карт на сайт wordpress не видно хинта 2 - почему прозрачный фон хинта становится белым? http://jsfiddle.net/9fywhmc0/